# Why does android gradle plugin not automatically override/ignore a deprecated SDK?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say that you have a project A28 that uses android SDK 28 and          build tools 28.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
```

This project has a dependency on project B23 that uses android SDK 23 and tools 23.0.0

When building A28, the build will fail. Instead of getting a useful error, I'm getting that a bunch of files (everything in B23) is missing and can't be linked (because it wasn't compiled by gradle, but there is no indication of that).

The only thing that may hint at the issue is:

> WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.0) is
>   ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1. Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be
>   used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'"
>   from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
>   Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

But this says explicitly, that gradle will compile this project (B23) with 28.0.3 tooling version, not 23.0.0.

If I add

```
subprojects {
  afterEvaluate { project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
      android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to my `build.gradle` in order to explicitly override everything with buildTools 28 & sdk 28, the build succeeds.

#### Why does this happen? Am I missing something? Shouldn't the lower sdk & build tools already be overriden/ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the `buildToolsVersion` altogether, from both projects. that is because the latest version according to the `targetSdkVersion` will be used. even `28.0.2` is below the minimum requirement of `28.0.3` for Gradle plugin `3.2.1`.

Comment: Fair enough, but my issue is, that I'm getting the second project as an external dependency (via a package manager), and should not modify it. As long as it explicitly states a `buildToolsVersion`, the issue will be present.

Comment: @K.Gkinis `afterEvaluate` might be the only option then. setting these values as extra properties on the root project might be an improvement, eg. if there is more than one third party module using outdated build tools.